# How to create a row where one element floats right and another element floats left

Tags: html, css

I was trying to have one element that is an image of the left and text on the right but all in the same row. When I try a few different ways sometimes the image and the text stay on the left of the image grows when I didn't tough the size. I put a background color in the row_2 element and the element is not aligned with the image or the text the element is at the bottom about 200 px and the image and text are above that can get some help?

```css
 #row_2{
  width: 60%;
  height: 35%;
  background-color: aqua;
 }

 #text_container2{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  bottom: 25%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
 }
  
 #container_2{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  float: left; 
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
 }
  
  #balle_size{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
  <div id="row_2">
   <div id="container_2">
    <img src="https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/stock/2018/2/27/0/iStock-purple-geraniums-542945456.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.966.725.suffix/1519754224444.jpeg"  alt="image" id="balle_size">
   </div>

   <div id="text_container2">
    <p>words words more words and words </p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try with flexbox. It's might be help you. :)

Comment: you can use bootstrap also

Comment: I'll look at those now.

Comment: Hello @sarah. Do you need to use float concept? Or wanna use flex concept? Please let me know.+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `flexbox` you can achieve this(Good compatibility across cross browser and responsive as well)

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item"><img src="https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/stock/2018/2/27/0/iStock-purple-geraniums-542945456.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.966.725.suffix/1519754224444.jpeg"  alt="image" id="balle_size" width="100%"></li>
  <li class="flex-item">Some text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I can a few notes to look back on in the future. I'm sorry for the extra work I'm still learning.

Comment: It means you are comfortable with `float` left and right properties

Comment: I'm sort of okay with it. this works really nicely though. Thank you

Comment: Pleasure is all mine @SarahWinters if you need more help we are here to help you.

Comment: One more question how would I flip it if I wanted the image on the right and the text on the left.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I'm going to google a lot of these functions thank you really.

Comment: @SarahWinters This is where we got another plus point for using `felx` without changing `HTML` we can do this just play with `flex-direction` like in you case you want to switch col use `flex-direction: row-reverse;`. Just Google more about `flexbox` for me the useful [link](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv)

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code. May it helps you.

```
#row_2{
    width: 60%;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: aqua;
    display: inline-block;
}

#text_container2{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}

#container_2{
    float: left;
    width: 50%; 
}

#balle_size{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```